# What is the way used by the ORM Django and the DB postgreSQL for the B-tree index?

Tags: django, orm, b-tree

I have this B-tree each number is the id of a member

[image]

How the ORM Django count each element (with this select : **SELECT count(*)
FROM member** , the way used is:

```
23 -> 11 -> 33 -> 1 -> 13 -> 25 -> 77
```

or

```
23 -> 11 -> 1 -> 13 -> 33 -> 25 -> 77
```

And how the ORM Django travel the B-tree with thes select :

```
SELECT last_name
FROM member

SELECT *
FROM member
ORDER BY member_id
```

The travel is level by level or branch by branch ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ORM. The ORM just constructs the query. How it is evaluated is determined by the database management system, not by the ORM.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't knew it. But with Django I use postgreSQL, you know how evaluate it?